# How to change the native blue background of a SAPUI5 application

Tags: css, background, sapui5

### Environment

Framework : **SAPUI5 V1.38.39**
IDE : WebIDE

### The problem

On Native **SAPUI5 application** the native "background" (I mean the page is in the center and around there is this blue background, i indicated them whith a red circle one the picture):
[image]
**I would like to change it** by the color of my choice, in **css** if possible

### To duplicate the problem:

in webIDE do : New>Project from Template then in SAPUI5 Version select SAPUI5 1.38 and select SAPUI5 Application. You will land on the same view with this blue background

### What I tried:

In the file style.css :

```css
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f5 !important;
}
```

```css
.sapUiBody {
    background-color: #f0f0f5 !important;
}
```

```css
#content{
    background-color: #f0f0f5 !important;
}
```

But none of those try worked :(
Do someone have a solution to change this background by the color of my choice ?

Comment: Have you read up on [theming](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/497c27a8ee26426faacd2b8a1751794a) in UI5?

Comment: Yes, I read and seen "the UI theme designer also lets you add custom CSS, which gives you the freedom to adapt basically everything" but my 3 try didn't work in CSS and I get out of idea (also for the version V1.38 of sapui5 their is only the themes sap_hcb & sap_bluecrystal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS class that contains the background color gradient is called `sapMShellGlobalOuterBackground`. In your `styles.css`, add:

```
.sapMShellGlobalOuterBackground {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #4A412A;
}
```

The result:

[image: World's ugliest background color]